# string containing equals "=" and no quotes convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Im currently stuck trying to convert a string into JSON in javascript.

the string im getting from the server is:

```
"{knee=true, centered=true}"
```

the outcome im looking for is something like this:

```
{ knee: true, centered: true}
```

but since the string is using equals and there are missing quotes the JSON.parse isnt working, I dont know how to solve this. any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you have more details on the specifics of this format? It's impossible to write a good parser unless you know what the contents of the string may contain.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Please may you consider fixing the source?

Comment: @evolutionxbox As far as I understand the server sends the invalid JSON format and the question is how to fix it on client side. It's even described in the question that the string is not valid JSON.

Comment: @jabaa understood. It's always better to fix it at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could do was this  ... It returns value of object in strings though it seems to work perfect ! ( Actually this one challenged me so I had to do it )  :-)

```
let str = "{knee = true, centered = true}";
str = str.replaceAll('{', '')
str = str.replaceAll('}', '')
str = str.split(",")
str = Object.assign({}, str);
let key_value;
let key;
let val;
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(str).length; i++) {

  key_value = str[i].split("=");
  key = String(key_value[0]);
  val = key_value[1];
  str[i] = val;
  delete Object.assign(str, {[key]: str[i]
  })[i];

}

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have nested things or strings with commas or brackets in them, you could replace all `{` with `{"`, `=` with `":`, and `,`  with `, "`:

```js
const str = "{knee=true, centered=true}"

console.log(
  JSON.parse(str.split('{').join('{"').split('=').join('":').split(', ').join(', "'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more specifics it's impossible to verify how correct this is, but if I was to make some assumptions:

- An object is a set of key/value pairs surrounded by `{` and `}`
- Key/value pairs are separated by `,`
- Any arbitrary whitespace is allowed around key/value pairs
- A key and value are separated by a `=`
- Values can only hold the value `true` or `false` which should be translated to a JavaScript boolean

...then parsing can be done through some regular expressions and string manipulations.

```
const objectRegExp = /^\{(.*)}$/;

function parseNJson(str) { // notJSON
  const match = objectRegExp.exec(str);
  if (!match) {
    throw new Error('This is not NJson');
  }

  const [, keyValuesBlock] = match;
  const keyValueStatements = keyValuesBlock.split(',');
  const keyValues = keyValueStatements.map(statement => statement.split('='));

  return keyValues.reduce((result, [keyStr, valueStr]) => {
    const key = keyStr.trim();
    
    const trimmedValue = valueStr.trim();
    let value;
    if (trimmedValue === 'true') {
      value = true;
    } else if (trimmedValue === 'false') {
      value = false;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported value ${trimmedValue}`);
    }

    return Object.assign(result, { [key]: value });
  }, {});
}
```

This will easily fall apart if any assumptions were incorrect, like "what if values can be strings? What if strings can be quoted with double quotes? What if they can also be surrounded by single quotes? What if numbers are supported? What if hexadecimal numbers are supported?"

If the data being sent on the server is a standard format, they should be able to tell you "this was formatted as X" so you can find a spec-compliant X parser. Or you could insist data is sent as JSON instead, since that's a super common exchange format. The best thing is that the server and client are using a common, well-defined message formatting spec so you don't accidentally break things whenever receiving or sending data that has characteristics you didn't account for.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! The data Im getting from the server is going to look like the example I gave every single time, so the parsing i need to do is only going to be configures once and it should work every time Im calling the data.