# What data format is this and how do I import it to python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a JSON like format from logs. It is different from JSON:

1. It doesn't have quotation marks around the name
2. There are "=" signs instead of ":"

What is this format called and how do I import it cleanly into python. Here is a small sample:

```
{
    accumulator = {
        animation_speed = 0.5,
        ingredients = {
            {
              "processing-unit",
              20
            },
            {
              "copper-plate",
              20
            },
            {
              "steel-plate",
              20
            },
            {
              "electric-engine-unit",
              10
            }
          },
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this file from?

Comment: Does not seem to match any of the common file formats. It depends on where you got it from like @S.B says. 
It could even be a regular text file

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67943023/3216427 it is not identical, but I see similarities, and its answers might help you a little bit?

Comment: Just like in that question, I'm afraid the answer might be that you have to write your own parser for it. Or fix the server that's producing this non-standard format if you have the ability to do that.

Comment: This looks like the question from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997216/how-to-parse-a-string-containing-equal-signs-to-object) The author says it's from Apache Kafka.

Comment: get this kind of data from a regular log file in text format. The data is produced by a mod parsing game files and dumping it into this file. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Ill be writing my own parser